# A .then doesn't run after the promise gets resolved on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, es6-promise

Code:

```
var promiseResolve, promiseReject;    

function iterateRules(rules, params, i = 0) {

    CWevents.putRule(rules[i], function(err, data) {    // This is an async function with a callback
        if (err) console.log(err); promiseReject(err)

        responses++
        params['Lambda_invoke']['SourceArns'].push(data.RuleArn)

        if(responses == rules.length){ promiseResolve("Success"); console.log("Resolved")} 
        // After two responses are confirmed, this if does run and I get the "Resolved"
    })
    i++
    if(i < rules.length){
        setTimeout( function(){
            iterateRules(params['CW_rules']['Rules'], params, i)
        }, 50)
    }
}

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve() 
// This part is added solely for the code to make sense, it's taken out of a 
// bigger script and lots of unnecessary data is removed 
})
.then((Item) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                promiseReject = reject;
                promiseResolve = resolve;
                iterateRules(params['CW_rules']['Rules'], params)
            })
}) .then((res) => {
        console.log("This ran")
   })
```

The `iterateRules` function is supposed to run an asynchronous function multiple times, and resolve the Promise it's called in when the last response is acquired. The `if(responses == rules.length)` does run as expected and logs the "Resolved" in the console. Everything is successful, no errors.

Beneath is the context of this code, the `iterateRules` function is executed, but the `.then` that comes after, isn't. If I put a `resolve()` inside the promise directly, it does execute. What might be wrong with this script? I tried running a simple version of it that looks like this separately:

```
var res, rej;

function dude(){
    res()
}

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    res = resolve;
    dude()
}).then((dude) => {
    console.log("resolved")
})
```

And it does in fact work, so I'm very confused. What might cause the problem?

Comment: First thing I notice is you need to not use the [Promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: this line `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    resolve()})` makes zero sense? Why are you making a promise then immediately resolving it?

Comment: Because it's a piece of a 300 line script and it contains sensitive data, lots of non-default functions and would be unnecessary for the case. So I replaced it with a simple `resolve()` for the script to make sense.

Comment: Wow, this code is an async nightmare...I'm not sure where to begin.  is `iterateRules` supposed to return a promise?

Comment: No, `iterateRules` just resolves the promise it's called in when all the requests are resolved. It should at least.

Comment: is there a reason why you cant make iterateRules return a promise? passing a global scope var like `promiseResolve` is not a good practice

Comment: I'm pretty new to promises so I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about. Can you please clarify?

Comment: see my answer below....hard to explain in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `iterateRules()` return a promise (since it is asynchronous). I would also promisify the `CWevents.putRule()` function so you can accomplish some code like the below:

```
function iterateRules(rules, params) {
    return Promise.all(rules.map(rule => {
        return CWevents.putRule(rule)
    })).then((data) => {
        params['Lambda_invoke']['SourceArns'].push(data.RuleArn)
    })
}
```

Then your handler for iterateRules would become:

```
iterateRules(rules,params).then(()=>{
    // Do something...
})
```

Comment: and for the purists, yes i know there is a shorthand for `CWevents.putRule()`, but it is less readable if you dont know about `(val) => {return val}` and `(val) => val`

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented it a bit differently using `Promise.all()`, but it fixed the problem and looks much more neat.